# Cannot find symbol HttpClient

Tags: java, compiler-errors, httpclient

These kinds of things never made much sense to me. I am trying to use this class:

http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-httpclient-2.0.1/src/java/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.java.shtml

Every time I compile I get a bunch of errors such as:

```
> /ChunkedInputStream.java:85: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : class HttpMethod
> location: class .ChunkedInputStream
>     private HttpMethod method;
>             ^
> /ChunkedInputStream.java:96: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : class HttpMethod
> location: class .ChunkedInputStream
>         final InputStream in, final HttpMethod method) throws IOException {
>                                     ^
> /ChunkedInputStream.java:283: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : variable HttpConstants
> location: class .ChunkedInputStream
>         String dataString = HttpConstants.getString(baos.toByteArray());
>                             ^
> /ChunkedInputStream.java:303: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : class Header
> location: class .ChunkedInputStream
>         Header[] footers = HttpParser.parseHeaders(in);
>         ^
> /ChunkedInputStream.java:303: cannot find symbol
> symbol  : variable HttpParser
> location: class .ChunkedInputStream
>         Header[] footers = HttpParser.parseHeaders(in);
```

Shouldn't I have access to these objects because it is a part of the package org.apache.commons.httpclient; ? I also added the apache http client jars to my application. What gives?

Comment: do you have http-core on your classpath?

Comment: Yes I have httpcore-4.2.1.jar and httpclient-4.2.1.jar

Comment: what are you using to build your project? ant/maven/something else? do you use IDE? You would be better of using something like maven to manage your dependencies trust me (MadProgrammer has a point there).

Comment: I am just using a text editor and the application is in Tomcat

Comment: don't torture yourself, get an IDE and maven and use it

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a choice in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure imports are at top of your program. Having jars in project is not enough, unless those classes are not in same package, you need to explicitly `import` those classes to your program.

Comment: I added this: import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*; and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Make sure those jars in classpath. Are you using any IDE?

Comment: I am not using an IDE. I have httpcore-4.2.1.jar and httpclient-4.2.1.jar in my shared/lib folder which i used when I compile

Answer (score 0):

From memory, the HttpClient has (@ least one) project dependency on HttpCore & knowing apache, probably more, like io-commons & logging

I ended up linking

- Apache-mime4j
- Commons-codec
- Commons-logging
- Httpclient (4)
- HttpCore (4)
- HttpMime (4)

But this might be overkill, but it works for me

Comment: i have commons-codec-1.6.jar, commons-logging-1.1.1.jar, fluent-hc-4.2.1.jar, httpclient-4.2.1.jar,httpclient-cache-4.2.1.jar,httpcore-4.2.1.jar, httpmime-4.2.1.jar - i don't have apache-mime4j but it wasn't included with apache httpclient

Comment: It still sounds like a missing resource issue.  If you're not using an IDE how are you compiling the program?  Ant? By hand?

Comment: I know, this is incredibly stupid, but make sure ALL the jar dependencies are in supplied in the class path argument, including any sub dependencies that the httpClient may require